# Rails Error NoMethodError in UsersController#show error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

`undefined method 'key?' for nil:NilClass`

This is the error I am getting while going through M. Hartl's Rails Tutorial. Also, after saving my user_controller.rb file and refreshing `http://localhost:3000/users/1`, I get another error that is:

```
Gem::LoadError in UsersController#show

bcrypt-ruby is not part of the bundle. Add it to Gemfile.
```

bcrypt-ruby is in my gemfile however, and after I refresh again this error is gone. Its just a bit weird.

Here is my user_controller.rb

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
  end
end
```

and here is my show.html.erb

```
<%= @user.name %>, <%= @user.email %>
```

Thank you all very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Had the same problem:  (try step 3 first)

1. rails command line> gem install bcrypt-ruby
2. rails command line> bundle install  (not sure this was needed)
3. Restart the Rails Server  (you could try this first -this may have been the only step needed)

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar difficulties.  To solve it, all I had to do was restart the rails server and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem

it worked after i restarted the server