# gem install bcrypt (LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, bcrypt

Still learning with the rails tutorial... I've been setting bcrypt (apparently) successfully from:

```
gem install bcrypt --platform=ruby
```

as it says

```
Successfully installed bcrypt-3.1.11
(...)
1 gem installed
```

But after adding this line in user.rb

```
has_secure_password
```

I run a rails test, expecting just a red light for not having required a password confirmation in the user_test.rb file and actually I get an error preceded by

```
You don't have bcrypt installed in your application. Please add it to your Gemfile and run bundle install
```

OK then, I follow these instructions and bcrypt-3.1.11 (x86-mingw32) is in the list. Again I try a rails test and here I get a LoadError

```
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bcrypt-3.1.11-x86-mingw32/lib/bcrypt.rb:16:in 'require': cannot load such file -- bcrypt_ext (LoadError)
```

And that's right, there is no file named bcrypt_ext anywhere! So what ?

> I'm wondering about DevKit as mentionned here  [Rails Gem::LoadError in UsersController#new](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9648487/rails-gemloaderror-in-userscontrollernew?rq=1) 
>   In my first try, it is stated "temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit..."

Comment: Could you include the contents of your Gemfile?

Comment: My Gemfile is too large to be sent in a comment, I am afraid

Comment: This is windows only problem. Check gem list with `gem list bcrypt` there might be more than one bcrypt installed remove (x86-mingw32) then it should work.

Comment: There are actually more than one bcrypt. I had to run gem uninstall bcrypt to see that I have bcrypt-3.1.11 and bcrypt-3.1.11-x86-mingw32. I can't remove that last one because of a dependent gem.

Comment: The problem occurs frequently and I don't know if it's a specific problem with windows, but the solution is each time the one proposed by Pradeep Sapkota: remove the second gem  (x86-mingw32).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kart-able;

try the following steps which worked for me:

- remove anything related to bcrypt from your Gemfile
- Enter the following information into your Gemfile

  gem 'bcrypt', git: 'https://github.com/codahale/bcrypt-ruby.git', :require => 'bcrypt'

Run 'bundle install' at the root of your project and it should work.

Comment: After removing bcrypt and bcrypt-ruby from my Gemfile, I first run a 'bundle install' and see that bcrypt is still living with a 'gem list bcrypt'.

Comment: But it's OK I removed bcryt-buby and then I could remove bcrypt itself